# Assign value to column based on multiple condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select using multiple dates and assign value to a column based on max value of the price based on those 2 dates. could be helpful if someone can point out if this is fastest way possible.

I have tried this code but it created a new row and doesn't change existing row.

```py
def updateRecord(dfIn, starDate, endDate):
    mask = (dfIn['date'] <= endDate) & (dfIn['date'] >= startDate)
    new_df = dfIn.loc[mask]
    if len(new_df) == 0:
        return dfIn

    dfIn.loc[dfIn.loc[mask].price.max(), 'highest'] = 1
    dfIn.loc[dfIn.loc[mask].price.min(), 'lowest'] = 1
    return dfIn
```

```
date       price  highest  lowest
2000-05-01 04:00:00    4.439730             0            0
2000-05-02 04:00:00    4.209830             0            0
2000-05-03 04:00:00    4.109380             0            0
2000-05-04 04:00:00    3.953130             0            0
2000-05-05 04:00:00    4.040180             0            0
2000-05-08 04:00:00    3.933040             0            0
2000-05-09 04:00:00    3.765630             0            0
2000-05-10 04:00:00    3.546880             0            0
2000-05-11 04:00:00    3.671880             0            0
2000-05-12 04:00:00    3.843750             0            0
2000-05-15 04:00:00    3.607150             0            0
2000-05-16 04:00:00    3.774560             0            0
2000-05-17 04:00:00    3.620540             0            0
2000-05-18 04:00:00    3.598220             0            0
2000-05-19 04:00:00    3.357150             0            0
2000-05-22 04:00:00    3.212060             0            0
2000-05-23 04:00:00    3.064740             0            0
2000-05-24 04:00:00    3.131700             0            0
2000-05-25 04:00:00    3.116630             0            0
2000-05-26 04:00:00    3.084830             0            0
2000-05-30 04:00:00    3.127230             0            0
2000-05-31 04:00:00    3.000000             0            0
2000-06-01 04:00:00    3.183040             0            0
2000-06-02 04:00:00    3.305810             0            0
.....
2000-06-30 04:00:00    3.261160             0            0
```

desired outcome should be that rows should be updated as below:

```
df = updateRecord(df, '2000-05-01 04:00:00', '2000-05-31 04:00:00')

df output should be:

2000-05-01 04:00:00    4.439730             1            0
2000-05-31 04:00:00    3.000000             0            1
```

my current code creates a new row instead of updating existing row.

Comment: Your outcome is not clear. Could you include a dataframe with desired outcome?

Comment: @run-out I have updated the results

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is not the best way.

```
def updateRecord(dfIn, starDate, endDate):
    df_o = dfIn.loc[(dfIn['date'] <= endDate) & (dfIn['date'] >= startDate)]
    if len(df_o) == 0:
        return dfIn
    # What is supposed to happen if len(df_o) > 0?
    idx = df_o['price'].argmax()
    df_o.at[idx,'highest'] = 1

    idx_l = df_o['price'].argmin()
    df_o.at[idx_l,'lowest'] = 1

    return df_o
```

Hope it works.

Comment: if length is greater than zero means I can update mean there is min and or max

Comment: Doesn't work.  because it only updates min and max for all of df not selected df.

Comment: Is the selected `df` the one defined in the first line? i.e. `df_o` in the code above?

Comment: not sure what you mean? so the resulting update is happening to the whole dfIn.. meaning not happening between dates.

Comment: Do you only want the highest and lowest rows to be in the `df`?

Comment: I want to be able to change the full df. so I need this df_o.at[idx,'highest'] = 1 to be dfIn.at[idx,'highest'] = 1.  Which works.  Thanks again for you help

Answer (score 0):

This works, but brings the selected DataFrame. If you want the same but bringing the entire DataFrame I can do it too.

```
def updateRecord(dfIn, startDate, endDate):
    mask = (dfIn['date'] <= endDate) & (dfIn['date'] >= startDate)
    new_df = dfIn.loc[mask]
    if len(new_df) == 0:
        return dfIn
    new_df['highest']=np.where(new_df.price==new_df.price.max(),1,0)
    new_df['lowest']=np.where(new_df.price==new_df.price.min(),1,0)
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this.

```py
def updateRecord(dfIn, starDate, endDate):
    mask = (dfIn['date'] <= endDate) & (dfIn['date'] >= startDate)
    if sum(mask) == 0:
        return dfIn

    # You want the argmax[min] for the given mask, not the entire DF, as you stated.
    dfIn.loc[dfIn.loc[mask, 'price'].argmax(), 'highest'] = 1
    dfIn.loc[dfIn.loc[mask, 'price'].argmin(), 'lowest'] = 1

    return dfIn
```